# Benefits of migrating DWT or Razor templates to DXA in SDL web 8

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I know there are benefits of migrating existing templates to DXA, like no more need to know Tridion syntax, instead of use Spring MVC in application side, no need to use file system or legacy system instead use Broker DB to store whole application data, which will eventually decrease the load on servers and will increase website performance/load time. Is there any other benefits moving to DXA?

Answer (score 2):

**DXA Benefits:**

- Faster time to market and easy maintenance
- Speed up your deployment time by eliminating unnecessary programming efforts.
- Immediately access up to 70% of the most common use cases.
- Free up resources to focus on custom requirements.
- Benefit from open-source access to community advice and additional features.
- Achieve faster performance, handle more users, and use fewer resources using the GraphQL content API.

Refer to this [DXA datasheets](https://www.sdl.com/resources/downloads/data-sheet/tridion-dx/tridion-sites/dxa.html) detailed information about the DXA features.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

I have to say, I'm a bit chary of "marketing" bullet points about vague benefits. From a practical standpoint, the primary benefits are:

- Templating code is versioned and managed with branches outside Tridion
- Assuming you can factor the coding logic out of your views, you can cover some of your testing needs with unit tests.
- Releases of your application also include all your templating (and probably your front-end code, which you probably don't want to publish from Tridion)
- Changes to your HTML don't require a publish of the whole site.

There is perhaps some marginal benefit in being able to use programmers with less knowledge of Tridion, but this is mostly just replaced by having to have knowledge of DXA, and you will still need to have Tridion expertise available.

While in principle DXA is a community open-source project, all the committers work for SDL, and you will want to get their attention if you have problems, so you'll be going through support in much the same way as you are used to. The ambiguity regarding exactly what the support position is for DXA is unhelpful, and I hope for a future in which this is much clearer.

The typical Tridion customer still has very specific requirements, so most likely, you'll still be doing a lot of bespoke work.

With these provisos, I still think moving to DXA is a positive step. It's not a cure-all, but you'll be going in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Besides mentioned ones, I would like to point out rendering.
In classic DWT, rendering takes some time. It might depend on how much the template is large.
In case of DXA, the content is usually rendered in JSON format, which is stored in Broker. (And, such rendering is much faster.)

Naturally, significantly faster rendering can play a role in case of massive (re-)publishing.